# Refresh Table in GTK

Tags: c, gtk

I've done a little program in C with GTK with a window, a box and a table inside the box. The table is painted with some files. I'd like to refresh the table with other data but I don't know how.

This code launches a window with a `GtkTable`. This table is filled in the timer handle function. First time draw three lines in order 1,2,3 and last time write three lines in order 3,2,1. But the table never refreshes.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *table);
gboolean launched;

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vboxgeneral;
    gchar *title;
    GtkWidget *table;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* WINDOW */
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    title = "Test GtkTable";

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), title);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 100);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    /* ADDING GTKHBOX TO MAIN WINDOW */
    vboxgeneral = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

    /* ADDING GTKTABLE TO VBOX */
    table = gtk_table_new(1,1,FALSE);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vboxgeneral), table, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    /* SHOW ALL */
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    /* ACTIONS */
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /* START TIMER */
    g_timeout_add(10000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) window);
    time_handler(table);

    gtk_main();


    return 0;
}



static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *table)
{
    GtkWidget *widget;
    gboolean result = FALSE;

    /* ADDING TABLE DEFINITION */

    if(!launched)
    {
        table = gtk_table_new(3,1,FALSE);

        widget = gtk_label_new("File 1");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 2");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 1, 2);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 3");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 2, 3);


        launched = TRUE;
        result = TRUE;

        g_print("Timer executed fisrt time!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        table = gtk_table_new(3,1,FALSE);

        widget = gtk_label_new("File 3");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 2");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 1, 2);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 1");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 2, 3);



        result = FALSE;
        g_print("Timer executed last time!\n");
    }

     gtk_widget_draw(table, NULL);


    return result;
}
```

Comment: You put your data in the table in `fill_data()`, but you didn't include that function here. On the other hand, you included lots of code that is irrelevant to the problem. Can you create a minimal example that shows what you want to do?

Comment: I have modified the question with the code that you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks! Only please don't remove your original question, or the question won't make sense in the future. I edited it to put the original question back at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

- You didn't add your vbox to your window. That can be done with the following code:
  `gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vboxgeneral);`
- You were passing the wrong parameter (the table widget) to your time_handler function. In that function, you created a new table losing the previous one which you packed into a vbox. What you can do is destroy the previous table and create a new one with the new labels and pack it into the vbox.
- The call time_handler(table) made in your main function is completely unnecesary. The timer already does that for you.

The revised code I made (a working code which does what you asked) as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *table);
gboolean launched;

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vboxgeneral;
    gchar *title;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    title = "Test GtkTable";

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), title);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 100);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);

    /* ADDING GTKHBOX TO MAIN WINDOW */
    vboxgeneral = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 0);

    /* This step was missing! */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vboxgeneral);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    /* START TIMER */
    /* refresh in 1 second, change to the desired amount */
    g_timeout_add(1000, (GSourceFunc) time_handler, (gpointer) vboxgeneral);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}



static gboolean time_handler(GtkWidget *vbox)
{
    GtkWidget *widget;
    static GtkWidget *table = NULL;
    gboolean result = FALSE;

    /* if you want only the new labels to appear and not the previous ones you can: */
    /* 1. destroy the table and create a new one. This will be done */
    /* 2. hide all previous labels in the table and create and show the new ones */

    if (table != NULL) {
        /* destroy previous table packed into vbox */
        gtk_widget_destroy(table);
    }

    table = gtk_table_new(3,1,FALSE); /* create new table for the new labels */

    if(!launched) {

        widget = gtk_label_new("File 1");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 2");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 1, 2);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 3");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 2, 3);


        launched = TRUE;
        result = TRUE;

        g_print("Timer executed first time!\n");
    } else {
        /* table = gtk_table_new(3,1,FALSE); */

        widget = gtk_label_new("File 3");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 0, 1);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 2");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 1, 2);
        widget = gtk_label_new("File 1");
        gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(widget), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), widget, 0, 1, 2, 3);


        launched = FALSE;
        result = FALSE;
        g_print("Timer executed last time!\n");
    }

    /* ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE TO THE VBOX */
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), table, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    /* VERY IMPORTANT: SHOW ALL THE NEW LABELS PACKED INTO THE TABLE */
    gtk_widget_show_all(table);

    return result;
}
```